# DialogFragment is not going up when soft keyboard is on

Tags: android, layout, view, keyboard

I have dialogs in other places in the app that work just fine(keyboad doesn't hide the view) , but in this particular new dialog I wrote it doesn't move the view up when the keyboard is on. I can't figure out why..

My dialog's layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/MyLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/dialog_background"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    custom:maxHeight="@dimen/dialog_max_height"
    custom:maxWidth="@dimen/dialog_max_width" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="something" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/SomeEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:minHeight="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="right|top"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textColor="@color/edit_text_text_color"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/SomeButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dialog_button_height"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:text="text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I have

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
```

set in my manifest.

Comment: Show your manifest file.

Comment: I have  `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" `. But it works in other dialogs in the app just fine, so I figured it doesn't have anything to do with that. I also tried adjustResize though, it didn't help

Comment: try this property  `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in your activity in manifest

Comment: I wrote that I tried that, but it didn't help unfortunately

Answer (score 4):

Found the solution :

I put :   `getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);`

in the onCreateDialog callback

Comment: I think it should be "WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN" to prevent UI smashing.

Answer (score 1):

Since SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE is deprecated starting android 30, you should use `Window.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(boolean decorFitsSystemWindows)`

Here is example for DialogFragment

```
class MyDialog extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        getDialog().getWindow().setDecorFitsSystemWindows(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_dialog, container, false);

        v.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener((v1, insets) -> {
            Insets imeInsets = insets.getInsets(WindowInsets.Type.ime());
            v1.setPadding(0, 0, 0, imeInsets.bottom);
            return insets;
        });
  
        getDialog().getWindow().setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false);    
        return v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue and resolved by keeping getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)
inside oncreateview